# How to create plist using Zwoptex?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, plist, zwoptex

I am new in Cocos2d game developing. I have use more images for CCSprite animations. I am using that image like below code :

```
CCAnimation *animate=[CCAnimation animation];
[animate addFrameWithFilename:@"Criter1.png"];
[animate addFrameWithFilename:@"Criter2.png"];
[animate addFrameWithFilename:@"Criter3.png"];
[animate addFrameWithFilename:@"Criter4.png"];
CCAnimate *animation=[CCAnimate actionWithDuration:0.3f animation:animate restoreOriginalFrame:YES];
CCRepeatForever *repeat=[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animation];
[sprite runAction:repeat];
```

But i want to create a `.plist` fie and use that in my code. So how can i make `.plist` file and use it in my code ?

Comment: What does the code in your question have to do with creating a plist file and using it in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want to create a .plist fie and use that in my code.

Ans : I am telling you line by line. please follow this and create `.plist` file.

1- First open Zwoptex.

[image]

2- Click "Create a new document"

3- Click "Publish setting". (right side top corner)

4- Set your plist name & save target.

5- Click save.

[image]

6- Set your plist file width and height .(left side bar)

7- Drag and drop your all image.

[image]

8- Click "Layout" (Top left)

[image]

9- Then click "Publish" (top left)

[image]

10- Your .plist file is save in your target position.

> how can i make .plist file and use it in my code ?

```
// First add that .plist file and .png  in your project.

[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"sample.plist"];// retrive plist

NSMutableArray* CharAnim = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png",i]];
    [CharAnim addObject:frame];
}

CCAnimation *animate=[CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:CharAnim delay:0.045f];// Animation duration
CCAnimate *animation=[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animate];
CCRepeatForever *repeat=[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animation];// for repeat forever
[sprite runAction:repeat];// add on your sprite
```

I think this will help you. :)